# $Cov(X_t , X_{t-2})$ in $AR$ model.

Tags: probability, statistics, time-series

What is $Cov(X_t , X_{t-2})$ based on $Var({X_t})$ in model $AR(1)$. I tried using $X_t - \mu = a(X_{t-1} - \mu) + Z_t$ to find $X_{t-2}$ based on $X_t$ as fallow
$$ X_{t-2} = \frac{X_t - \mu - aZ_{t-1} - Z_t+a^2\mu}{a^2}$$ and then solving $Cov(X_t , X_{t-2})$ and i reach to something like
$$\frac{1}{a^2}Var(X_t) - \frac{1}{a}E[X_tZ_{t-1}] - \frac{1}{a^2}E[X_tZ_{t}]$$
but is coud i write $- \frac{1}{a}E[X_tZ_{t-1}] - \frac{1}{a^2}E[X_tZ_{t}]$ based on $Var({X_t})$ or it might be the case that question is wrong!?

Comment: You have $X_t - \mu = a^2(X_{t-2} - \mu)+ a Z_{t-1} + Z_t $ so assuming independence of the terms on the right hand side and $E[X_t]=E[X_{t-2}]=\mu$ and $Var[X_t]=Var[X_{t-2}]$, the covariance should be easy

Comment: Assuming $Var[X_t] = Var[X_{t-2}]$ i solved $Cov(X_{t-2}, a^2 (X_{t-2} - \mu) + aZ_{t-1} + Z_t +\mu)$ and i got the final answer $a^2Var[X_{t-2}]$ and by assumption $a^2Var[X_{t}]$  But why do we assume $Var[X_t] = Var[X_{t-2}]$  ?

Comment: If process is weakly stationary (which I assume it is), the autocovariance does not depend on time. The variance is the autocovariance at lag 0, so it does not depend on time. Thus, $Var(X_t) = Var(X_{t-h})$ for all $h$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us work with the AR(1) without the constant term $Y_t = X_t-\mu$ which is more direct. As mentioned by @Henry, you can write
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y_t &= aY_{t-1} + Z_t \\
&=a(aY_{t-2}+Z_{t-1})+Z_t \\
&=a^2Y_{t-2} + aZ_{t-1} + Z_t.
\end{aligned}
$$
With the above, you can calculate
$$
\begin{aligned}
Cov(Y_t, Y_{t-2}) &= Cov(a^2Y_{t-2} + aZ_{t-1}+Z_t, Y_{t-2}) \\
&= \dots \\
&= a^2 Var(Y_{t-2}).
\end{aligned}
$$
The intermediate steps have to be justified, but they are straightforward given that $Z_t$ is a noise process. We know that
$$
Var(Y_t) = \sigma^2/(1-a^2)
$$
for all $t$, where $Var(Z_t) = \sigma^2$. Thus
$$
Cov(Y_t, Y_{t-2}) = a^2 \frac{\sigma^2}{1-a^2}.
$$
Given that $Cov(X_t, X_{t-2}) = Cov(X_t-\mu,X_{t-2}-\mu) = Cov(Y_t, Y_{t-2})$, we have the answer.